# display 5 columns in one row using foreach in asp.net mvc the

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am stuck with one little thing, i am using MVC5 and trying to access table from database and showing it on View .
**Table with only one column** I did this way but not an efficient way, so need your help

```
@{
 int c = Model.Count();
}
```

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
             if (c >= 16)
             {
              <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }
             else if (c== 15)
             {
                 <tr></tr>
              <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }
             else if (c>=11)
             {
                 <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }
             else if (c==10)
              {
                 <tr></tr>
              <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }

             else if (c>=6)
             {
                 <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }
             else if (c==5)
             {
                <tr></tr>
              <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }

             else if (c>=0)
             {
                 <td>@Html.ActionLink( item.Name,"Jobs" ,new{name = item.Name})</td>   
             }
             c --;
         }

   </tr></Table>
```

5 colomns in a row and then, create new row with five columns.

Comment: Does your model have 5 properties that you want to display? What does the model look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model has additional properties such as `Column2`, `Column3` etc., then this will give you 5 columns:

```
<table class="table"  >
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Category, "Jobs")</td>
            <td>@Model.Column2</td>
            <td>@Model.Column3</td>
            <td>@Model.Column4</td>
            <td>@Model.Column5</td>
        }

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I have only one column and want to show it in 5 coloumns in a row. like